# Gratis windows CE 6.0 GPS program

Tags: gratis, gps, navigation, windows-ce

My dad bought an off-brand Windows CE 6.0 GPS device. It's not supported by the seller, or the company that does the default maps on it. I have regional maps for Singapore and Malaysia, and it would be *nice* to get it working for India.

I know Navit uses open street maps and works in Windows CE 5.0, but not 6.0.

Is there any third party Windows CE 6.0 GPS program?

To recap
 - I need it to work on Windows CE 6.0
 - It needs to use OSM and/or have maps for India
 - It needs to be free, though open-sourcedness is not a criteria
 - I need routing and all the *basics* you'd expect from a GPS program.  Turn by turn navigation, being able to set a destination on an on screen keyboard and so on.